# np.where on 2D array without masked array or any second argument

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, image-masking

I was checking out one code snippets, there was a code like below

```
z = [[True, False, True],[True, True, True],[False, False, False]]
xz, yz = np.where(z)
print(xz)
print(yz)
```

This returns

```
[0 0 1 1 1]
[0 2 0 1 2]
```

If I make

```
z = [[True, False, True],[True, True, True]]
```

I will get the same results as

```
[0 0 1 1 1]
[0 2 0 1 2]
```

When I make

```
z = [[True, False],[True, True]]
```

The result is

```
[0 1 1]
[0 0 1]
```

I was not able to find out what's it doing, This was presented in [SynthText repo](https://github.com/ankush-me/SynthText/blob/master/synthgen.py#L77) on github.
I would be appreciated if any one could help to understand what it does? And what's its application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider 2d-array such as matrices, `np.where(z)` helps to get elements' indices for which are True or nonzero. 2d-array indices have two components corresponding to each elements of the array as `[rows' number, columns' number]`.
The first variable, i.e. `xz` in your example, shows the rows' numbers for True or nonzero elements and `yz` shows the corresponding columns' numbers. The following code could be helpful in understanding:

```
xz = [1th-x, 2nd-x, 3rd-x]
yz = [1th-y, 2nd-y, 3rd-y]
nonzero_indices = [[1th-x, 1th-y], [2nd-x, 2nd-y], [3rd-x, 3rd-y]]
```

Using the following code will get the indices for each True or nonzero elements as it is shown as `nonzero_indices` in the code above:

```
print(np.transpose(np.where(z)))
```

Which will give `[[0 0] [1 0] [1 1]]`
Hope it be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you read carefully the documentation on [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), you find that it's equvivalent to `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()` in case you only provide the condition parameter, so the behaviour comes down to [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero).

```py
>>> z = np.array([[True, False], [True, True]])
```

You have three nonzero elements in this array, indexed by: `[0, 0]`, `[1, 0]`, `[1, 1]`

```py
>>> np.nonzero(z)
(array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

The first element of the tuple is the first index of every nonzero element (`[0, 1, 1]`), the second element of the tuple is the second index of every nonzero element (`[0, 0, 1]`).